# Select id and save it in a variable with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am identified a login with Windows Forms and Entity Framework. I want to be able to select the user ID and add it to a variable to use it as a kind of session variable system wide.

This is the code I am using

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{   
    var id = context.user.Where(x => x.email == textBox1.Text)
                         .Select(x => x.userId ).SingleOrDefault();
}

MessageBox.Show("Id" +id);
```

I get this message by box:

> idMicrosoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'1 [system.model.user]

What is the best way to get the id and save it in a variable and thus be able to use it in other forms?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question to be answered.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I sent it before finishing writing

Answer (score 2):

I'd write this query as

```
var id = context.user.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Email == textBox1.Text)?.UserId
```

Make sure you guard your code around what it means if `id` is null. If it can't be null and should **only** be one, `Single()` will work.